# Differential equation with fractional expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I consider this ODE:

$$ y'+\frac{1}{y}=\tau,\quad \tau>0,y(0)=c\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $$

For the homogeneous case $$ y'+\frac{1}{y}=0 $$
I get $ y(x)=\sqrt{c^2-2x} $.

For the inhomogeneous case I consider now

$ y(x)=\sqrt{(c(x))^2-2x}\\y'(x)=\frac{c'(x)\cdot c(x)-1}{\sqrt{(c(x))^2-2x}} $

and plugged into the differential equation I get this

$$ y'(x)+\frac{1}{y(x)}=\frac{c'(x)\cdot c(x)}{\sqrt{(c(x))^2-2x}}=\tau $$

From here I don't have any idea how to proceed further.

Comment: There is no "homogeneous case" in a non-linear DE. Not every DE has a symbolic solution, indeed those that do are an extremely thin subset, just add any term in $x$. However, this one is autonomous and thus after isolating $y'$ can be recognized as separable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Make life easier switching variables
$$y'+\frac{1}{y}=\tau \implies \frac 1{x'}+\frac{1}{y}=\tau\implies x'=\frac{y}{\tau  y-1}$$

Comment: Why do you replace $y'$ with the expression $\frac{1}{x'}$?

Comment: @hallo97. To make life much simpler (as I wrote)